# Webmail client with Gmail IMAP support?

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

A client is requesting a web interface where he can accept or reject forms that are submitted to hime via email. I would have normally just used Gmail, but I don't need half of that functionality.

I found Roundcube, and set it up, but I can't get it to take the IMAP settings from Gmail's servers. I also set up my own, by using CPanel on my serves which is hosted by Hostgator, and no go.

The SMTP settings work fine:

```
Server: ssl://smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
User: ****
Password: ****
```

Trying to send email...
SMTP send:  OK

But when I try to use Gmail's IMAP settings, I get the following error:

```
Connecting to ssl://imap.gmail.com...
IMAP connect:  NOT OK(Login failed for **** from 74.110.63.15. Could not connect to ssl://imap.gmail.com:993: Connection timed out)
```

I've tried multiple things, including contacting my server to see if the port was blocked (it wasn't), but nothing is working.

I thought that this would probably just happen with Gmail's IMAP server, but nope, when I use those settings it also gives me that error.

Should I be looking to do this a different way?

**EDIT 1:**
Output of `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` in Terminal from my laptop

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
Trying 173.194.76.108...
Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
'^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
new-host-10:~ charlescarver$
```

**EDIT 2:**
Confirmed that server is not blocking the port:

```
openssh
s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 
CONNECTED(00000003) 
...
```

**EDIT 3:** Config file:

```
<?php

$rcmail_config = array();

$rcmail_config['debug_level'] = 1;

$rcmail_config['log_driver'] = 'file';

$rcmail_config['log_date_format'] = 'd-M-Y H:i:s O';

$rcmail_config['syslog_id'] = 'roundcube';

$rcmail_config['syslog_facility'] = LOG_USER;

$rcmail_config['smtp_log'] = true;

$rcmail_config['log_logins'] = true;

$rcmail_config['log_session'] = true;

$rcmail_config['sql_debug'] = true;

$rcmail_config['imap_debug'] = true;

$rcmail_config['ldap_debug'] = true;

$rcmail_config['smtp_debug'] = true;

$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'ssl://imap.gmail.com';

$rcmail_config['default_port'] = 993;

$rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = 'PLAIN';

$rcmail_config['imap_delimiter'] = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_ns_personal'] = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_ns_other']    = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_ns_shared']   = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_force_caps'] = false;

$rcmail_config['imap_force_lsub'] = false;

$rcmail_config['imap_timeout'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['imap_auth_cid'] = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_auth_pw'] = null;

$rcmail_config['imap_cache'] = null;

$rcmail_config['messages_cache'] = false;

$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

$rcmail_config['smtp_port'] = 465;

$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = 'email';

$rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = 'pass';

$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_type'] = '';

$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_cid'] = null;

$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_pw'] = null;

$rcmail_config['smtp_helo_host'] = '';

$rcmail_config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['enable_installer'] = true;

$rcmail_config['log_dir'] = 'logs/';

$rcmail_config['temp_dir'] = 'temp/';

$rcmail_config['message_cache_lifetime'] = '10d';

$rcmail_config['force_https'] = false;

$rcmail_config['use_https'] = false;

$rcmail_config['login_autocomplete'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['login_lc'] = false;

$rcmail_config['auto_create_user'] = true;

$rcmail_config['skin_logo'] = null;

$rcmail_config['skin_include_php'] = false;

$rcmail_config['session_lifetime'] = 10;

$rcmail_config['session_domain'] = '';

$rcmail_config['session_name'] = null;

$rcmail_config['session_storage'] = 'db';

$rcmail_config['memcache_hosts'] = null; 

$rcmail_config['ip_check'] = false;

$rcmail_config['referer_check'] = false;

$rcmail_config['x_frame_options'] = 'sameorigin';

$rcmail_config['des_key'] = '*fq85DV6dJy4ZDf0y_oj$Mw7';

$rcmail_config['username_domain'] = 'email';

$rcmail_config['mail_domain'] = '';

$rcmail_config['password_charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';

$rcmail_config['sendmail_delay'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['max_recipients'] = 0; 

$rcmail_config['max_group_members'] = 0; 

$rcmail_config['useragent'] = 'Roundcube Webmail/'.RCMAIL_VERSION;

$rcmail_config['product_name'] = 'Requests';

$rcmail_config['include_host_config'] = false;

$rcmail_config['generic_message_footer'] = '';

$rcmail_config['generic_message_footer_html'] = '';

$rcmail_config['http_received_header'] = false;

$rcmail_config['http_received_header_encrypt'] = false;

$rcmail_config['mail_header_delimiter'] = NULL;

$rcmail_config['line_length'] = 72;

$rcmail_config['send_format_flowed'] = true;

$rcmail_config['dont_override'] = array();

$rcmail_config['identities_level'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['client_mimetypes'] = null;  

$rcmail_config['mime_magic'] = '/usr/share/misc/magic';

$rcmail_config['im_identify_path'] = null;

$rcmail_config['im_convert_path'] = null;

$rcmail_config['contact_photo_size'] = 160;

$rcmail_config['email_dns_check'] = false;

$rcmail_config['plugins'] = array();

$rcmail_config['message_sort_col'] = '';

$rcmail_config['message_sort_order'] = 'DESC';

$rcmail_config['list_cols'] = array('subject', 'status', 'from', 'date', 'size', 'flag', 'attachment');

$rcmail_config['language'] = null;

$rcmail_config['date_format'] = 'Y-m-d';

$rcmail_config['date_formats'] = array('Y-m-d', 'd-m-Y', 'Y/m/d', 'm/d/Y', 'd/m/Y', 'd.m.Y', 'j.n.Y');

$rcmail_config['time_format'] = 'H:i';

$rcmail_config['time_formats'] = array('G:i', 'H:i', 'g:i a', 'h:i A');

$rcmail_config['date_short'] = 'D H:i';

$rcmail_config['date_long'] = 'Y-m-d H:i';

$rcmail_config['drafts_mbox'] = 'Drafts';

$rcmail_config['junk_mbox'] = 'Junk';

$rcmail_config['sent_mbox'] = 'Sent';

$rcmail_config['trash_mbox'] = 'Trash';

$rcmail_config['default_imap_folders'] = array('INBOX', 'Drafts', 'Sent', 'Junk', 'Trash');

$rcmail_config['create_default_folders'] = false;

$rcmail_config['protect_default_folders'] = true;

$rcmail_config['quota_zero_as_unlimited'] = false;

$rcmail_config['enable_spellcheck'] = true;

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_dictionary'] = false;

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_engine'] = 'pspell';

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_uri'] = '';

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_languages'] = NULL;

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_ignore_caps'] = false;

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_ignore_nums'] = false;

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_ignore_syms'] = false;

$rcmail_config['recipients_separator'] = ',';

$rcmail_config['max_pagesize'] = 200;

$rcmail_config['min_keep_alive'] = 60;

$rcmail_config['upload_progress'] = false;

$rcmail_config['undo_timeout'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['address_book_type'] = 'sql';

$rcmail_config['ldap_public'] = array();

$rcmail_config['autocomplete_addressbooks'] = array('sql');

$rcmail_config['autocomplete_min_length'] = 1;

$rcmail_config['autocomplete_threads'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['autocomplete_max'] = 15;

$rcmail_config['address_template'] = '{street}<br/>{locality} {zipcode}<br/>{country} {region}';

$rcmail_config['addressbook_search_mode'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['default_charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';

$rcmail_config['skin'] = 'default';

$rcmail_config['pagesize'] = 40;

$rcmail_config['addressbook_sort_col'] = 'surname';

$rcmail_config['addressbook_name_listing'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['timezone'] = 'auto';

$rcmail_config['dst_active'] = null;

$rcmail_config['prefer_html'] = true;

$rcmail_config['show_images'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['htmleditor'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['prettydate'] = true;

$rcmail_config['draft_autosave'] = 300;

$rcmail_config['preview_pane'] = false;

$rcmail_config['preview_pane_mark_read'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['logout_purge'] = false;

$rcmail_config['logout_expunge'] = false;

$rcmail_config['inline_images'] = true;

$rcmail_config['mime_param_folding'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['skip_deleted'] = false;

$rcmail_config['read_when_deleted'] = true;

$rcmail_config['flag_for_deletion'] = false;

$rcmail_config['keep_alive'] = 60;

$rcmail_config['check_all_folders'] = false;

$rcmail_config['display_next'] = false;

$rcmail_config['autoexpand_threads'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['top_posting'] = false;

$rcmail_config['strip_existing_sig'] = true;

$rcmail_config['show_sig'] = 1;

$rcmail_config['sig_above'] = false;

$rcmail_config['force_7bit'] = false;

$rcmail_config['search_mods'] = null;  

$rcmail_config['addressbook_search_mods'] = null; 

$rcmail_config['delete_always'] = false;

$rcmail_config['mdn_requests'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['mdn_default'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['dsn_default'] = 0;

$rcmail_config['reply_same_folder'] = false;

$rcmail_config['forward_attachment'] = false;

$rcmail_config['default_addressbook'] = null;

$rcmail_config['spellcheck_before_send'] = false;

$rcmail_config['autocomplete_single'] = false;
```

Comment: Looks like you are not reaching google's imap server at all : `Could not connect to ssl://imap.gmail.com:993: Connection timed out`. Maybe a firewall?

Comment: From google's website: `Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server - requires SSL: imap.gmail.com, Use SSL: Yes, Port: 993`. As for the firewall part, my computer does not have one set up, and it doesn't make sense that it wouldn't work on my network, considering this is going to be used on a different network than mine.

Comment: Try `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` from the machine that's connecting to gmail. What's the output?

Comment: Can you post you config file here without the comments?

Answer (score 1):

What imap_auth_type are you using?

In the config file try to set imap_auth_type to 'plain'.

```
// IMAP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or empty to use
// best server supported one)
$rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = 'PLAIN';
```

I could make it work with the newest version of Roundcube (v0.7.2) with the following config:

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'ssl://imap.gmail.com';
$rcmail_config['default_port'] = 993;
$rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = null;
$rcmail_config['username_domain'] = 'gmail.com';
```

I could then login with my gmail username (without @gmail.com) and gmail password.

The rest of the configuration was left in it's default setting.

Comment: Have you been able to set it up with Gmail's IMAP server?

Comment: @Charlie edited post, connected successfully to gmail imap with ssl

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having the same issue, tried both PLAIN and NULL, neither work. Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT: Contacted host who checked as I don't have SSH - I think they modified the firewall and all is working now using NULL

Comment: Still not working for me... I ended up using my hosts' mail account.